# Lowagie iText : Align paragraph vertically within Cell object

Tags: java, itext

I've seen a number of posts and tutorials on vertically aligning a paragraph object inside a PdfPCell object, but is there a way to set vertical alignment within a Cell object?

Currently I am using the Table class rather than the PdfPTable class and so I haven't found much with regards to this issue.

EDIT : Adding attempted solutions thus far. I have tried setting the alignment on the paragraph itself -

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("test", myFont);
p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

As well as setting the vertical alignment of the Cell object -

```
Cell c = new Cell(p);
c.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

Both of these have had no effect on the vertical alignment

Comment: The `Cell` class was removed from iText more than 5 years ago. There were good reasons why it was removed. You should not use it. You should also avoid using versions of iText with my name in the package names for numerous reasons that have been explained many times in different questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, This is the version of the library that I have to make do with and there are no other alternatives as extensive work has already occurred using this version with no plans to upgrade it

Comment: When you say *extensive work has already occurred*, I assume that you refer to work that was done years ago. If so, then it's time to upgrade. If not, I have been warning people many times that using an obsolete version of iText was a dead end and I would really like to know the reason why my advice wasn't followed.

Comment: Unfortunately it wasn't as long ago as you would think, and I'm not in a position to tell higher ups what they should and shouldn't be using; I am responsible for crafting a solution using the tools provided and no more, regardless of how outdated the tools may be. I'm not here to have a debate over whether there is still merit in using an outdated library or not, I'm here to find out if the outdated library can perform a certain piece of functionality

Comment: just by the by, can I assume that you downvoted my question?

Comment: It's not a good question: you don't show what you've tried. There is no code sample, nor proof of the fact that vertical alignment *doesn't work* ( http://lowagie.com/doesntwork ). Furthermore, you have a working solution: `PdfPTable`, yet you insist on using `Table` which is an approach that is discouraged by its original creator. If you are afraid to tell your higher-ups what they should or shouldn't use, just share their names and I'll address them in my own name. You're using *my name* in the title of your question, hence you shouldn't be surprised if I feel *personally* involved.

Comment: It's as if you don't realize that I'm on your side ;-) I've been in your situation too, a long time ago. I understand how hard it is. It's not you I want to convince. I know you're convinced. It's your bosses who need convincing.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not here to argue against what you are saying. Unfortunately due to reasons beyond my pay grade it is the older version of the library that is in use, and I have to make do with it. Attempted solutions added to the question

Answer (score 2):

Setting the alignment of a `Paragraph` to `Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE` is not supposed to work.

As I have deleted all the old versions of iText [that should no longer be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially), I can not test your other suggestion. However, I've found this really old copy of the very first tutorial I wrote about iText on stderr.org: [Chapter 5: Tables](http://stderr.org/doc/libitext-java-doc/www/tutorial/ch05.html).

In this tutorial, there's an example [Chap0506.java](http://stderr.org/doc/libitext-java-doc/www/examples/Chap0506.java) with the following lines:

```
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

The resulting PDF aligns the content of this cell correctly: [Chap0506.pdf](http://stderr.org/doc/libitext-java-doc/www/examples/Chap0506.pdf)

If this code doesn't work for you (which is what you are saying: you show this as one of the things you've tried in your question), you are probably not using an official version of iText that is flawed. I have personally removed every single instance of every single official server. You should consider it your duty to inform the powers-that-be at your company that they have provided you with a rogue version of iText that differs from the official version. Who knows what else is wrong with that version? Have you tested it for spyware?

Comment: after much deliberation I've decided to Convert all instance of Table to PdfPTables; I've also discovered that attributes such as padding can't be set at a per Cell basis

Comment: It shouldn't have been that much work to convert `Table` into `PdfPTable`, except if you need row span. Row span has only been implemented in `PdfPTable` in more recent versions.

Comment: Yes, it's not a difficult process in terms of complexity, more because of the amount of Table and Cell objects used throughout the application as well as methods that make use of Table specific functions

Comment: Even in the very first book I wrote about iText (published in November 2006), I already discouraged the use of the `Table` class. I'm very sorry, but the person who has the role of software architect at your company has done a really bad job. I feel your pain.